# Hyperlinks in WPF browser not working

Tags: wpf, browser

I have included a browser control in a WPF app I'm working on and when hyperlinks in the displayed web page are clicked nothing happens. To go to another page I have to right-click on the link and select open. Any ideas why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238694/example-using-hyperlink-in-wpf

Comment: Thank you @ShoaibRaza for the response but I don't see how this helps me...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to handle the `RequestNavigate` event:

```
link.RequestNavigate += (sender, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
};
```

Reference: [C# Hyperlink in TextBlock: nothing happens when I click on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742690/c-sharp-hyperlink-in-textblock-nothing-happens-when-i-click-on-it)

Comment: Thanks again. But how to I capture this event when it occurs in a web browser?

Comment: Try the steps under the heading **To create a hyperlink in a portion of a TextBlock** in the following link and see if that helps you:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304466.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really understanding... the web browser is displaying a web site - doesn't the method in your link require adding each hyperlink seperately?

Comment: I'm sorry @Shoaib Raza - it seems as though the problem is with the website... if I change to different websites, it works on some and not on others. I'll have to carry on researching...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Syed Shoaib Abidi's answer is just different syntax for the same thing, but:

```
link.RequestNavigate += UrlClicked;

...
private void Url_Clicked(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
}
```